# Tor starts but does not connect

Tags: configuration

I am trying to use Tor with Windows10 (I know, I know...).
All seems to go well but I can't connect to any site ("connecting" then back to the welcome page).
Same thing with the anti-virus and firewall ( G Data) deactivated.
Same thing with another bridge.
Same thing using another PC with Vista and another ISP.
Here is the log ; thank you for heeeelp.

```
13/10/2015 17:19:02.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
13/10/2015 17:19:02.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
13/10/2015 17:19:09.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
13/10/2015 17:19:09.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
13/10/2015 17:19:10.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 169.229.59.75:46328 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
13/10/2015 17:19:10.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
13/10/2015 17:19:10.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
13/10/2015 17:19:11.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
13/10/2015 17:19:11.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
13/10/2015 17:19:11.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
13/10/2015 17:19:11.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host A09D536DD1752D542E1FBB3C9CE4449D51298239 at 83.212.101.3:80) 
13/10/2015 17:19:11.200 [WARN] 2 connections have failed: 
13/10/2015 17:19:11.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
13/10/2015 17:19:11.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
13/10/2015 17:19:11.700 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: You write that you're using bridges. So I assume that your network is somehow censored. Did you try to use obfs3, obfs4 or other pluggable transports? What happens then?

Comment: No change with obfs3 or 4...

Answer (score 0):

The log you have pasted indicates you set the configuration option DisableNetwork, which is where your problem originates. Unset the option and it should work.

Comment: Fine, but how ? Where is this option ?

Comment: You will need to provide a bit more information, like exactly which software you're trying to use and how you're configuring it. Please update your question with that information.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
I'm just trying to use TOR 5.0.3 with no other software. I have just installed it.
How must the proxy be configured ?

Comment: this option is usually issued via control protocol when you close TorBrowser